# Building backlinks for keyword or url is best

Tags: seo, anchor

Some of seo masters build backlinks for their website. They come one two variants:

- The content of the anchor `<a> example.com </a>` (their domain)
- The content of the anchor `<a> example keyword </a>` (their keywords)

Which gives the best result ?

Answer (score 2):

yes you have to always change your anchor text whenever you create backlink. don't use same anchor text eg. if you want to create backlink for weight loss keyword you can use as follow :

1. weight loss tips
2. how to reduce weight
3. top 10 tips for weight loss

Comment: you prefer multiple keywords

Comment: or better yet don't use anchors at all.... anchors is the number one punishing factor. Always best to get a good mix of no anchors, no follows to deverse. Even non relevalnt anchors should be seeked, such as `read more`, `click here`, `find out more` `example.com` `http://example.com` and so forth.... keyword heavy or singular keywords is a number one ticket to penguin land.

Answer (score 1):

Building links with keywords in them is a blackhat practice known as link spam to Google.   Google has said that *any* link building is frowned upon.  They appear to only penalize sites when links are built with keywords. Building links with just your brand name or URL is unlikely to get you penalized.   Building links keyword rich anchor text will likely result in an over-optimization penalty and it will make it *harder* to rank for those keywords.

Comment: now what i do ?

Comment: Anurag's advice isn't totally wrong.  You can build links with keywords if you are *very* careful about it.   They need to be a small percentage of your links.   They need to vary the anchor text.   They have to come from pages with relevant content.   They can't be on pages with other spammy links.

Comment: already i got that problem so i asked about that because most of seo masters doing that

Comment: "SEO masters" that piss off Google arn't very good at their jobs.   Keyword rich link building is a short term strategy.   It only works until you get caught.

Comment: hm really true words